# fail2ban error: "WARNING Too much read error. Set the jail idle"

Tags: fail2ban

I get this error after a few days and it renders the fail2ban to ignore attacks on the specific filter:

```
2016-03-11 17:06:35,686 fail2ban.filter : ERROR  Unable to get stat on /srv/www/canalbases/logs/access.log
2016-03-11 17:06:36,687 fail2ban.filter : ERROR  Unable to get stat on /srv/www/canalbases/logs/access.log
2016-03-11 17:06:37,689 fail2ban.filter : ERROR  Unable to get stat on /srv/www/canalbases/logs/access.log
2016-03-11 17:06:37,689 fail2ban.filter : WARNING Too much read error. Set the jail idle
```

Comment: Is the file file present? Does it gets rotated by `logrotate` without notifying `fail2ban`? Is the volume writable and has free space? Is the file system damaged?

Comment: The file is present. How would I know if it's not notifying fail2ban?. The file is readable and has free space and the file system isn't damaged.